I am not a Moslem ,I hurt a Moslem and they cursed me can I get a cure?
I am not a Moslem ,I  hurt a Moslem people and they gave me money that was cursed ,how do I repent my sin and get forgiven if I can't meet that person ?

Please explain: you hurt them and they gave you money? That doesn't make sense without further explanation. What kind of curse do you suspect? Even if some Muslims suspect other Muslims to be magicians and fire worshipers, as far as I know, there is nothing written in the Quran on how to spell a curse. It would be completely against every ruling and saying. Please give details.
